# Unable to set required attribute for lightning input

Tags: aura, lightninginput, required-field, required

I'm currently looking to change the required attribute based on multiple scenarios.
So, I have a created input field with the required attribute as newAccRequire but by default, it's getting the true value.

But if I hardcoded directly required="false" it's working as expected.

Component

```
<aura:attribute name="newAccRequire" type="String" default="false"/>
<lightning:input aura:id="createNewAcc" type="String" name="inputAccName" 
                                 label="" value="{!v.leadRecord.Company}" 
                                 required="{!v.newAccRequire}"
                                 />
```

I have checked any references for this field on controller or helper, but I'm not using this field. Any idea why the field became mandatory automatically.

I have tried the solution but it's breaking in some situations. still, it's setting as true in some situations. any idea?

Screenshot:
[image]

My JS controller

```
console.log('@@@@Befor_exsiting_Search@@@@'+component.get('v.newAccRequire'));
    component.set("v.newAccRequire","false");
console.log('@@@@exsiting_Search@@@@'+component.get('v.newAccRequire'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute you are referencing should be of [type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_basic.htm) "Boolean" for representing true/false values. In JavaScript, all non-empty strings are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so if you use the `String` attribute type, it will be behave differently than if you declare the attribute as a `Boolean` type.

Comment: Nice answer, I just added a bit from an answer I was writing. Welcome to SFSE! If you haven't yet, please feel free to read about [answer] and take the [tour]. Looking forward to seeing future contributions from you.

Comment: Thank you, @sfdcfox! I have lurked and used several of your contributions to help solve my problems in the past. I hope to gain even more insight by interacting directly on SFSE. Cheers!

Comment: Your solution worked partially, could you please look in to this

Comment: @Pavantej you're setting the string `'false'` in your attribute (it has quotes). You should use the Boolean value `false` (no quotes).

Comment: `component.set("v.newAccRequire",false);` specifically. Remember when using strings with any length they will be evaluated as truthy in javascript.